# SSIS Foreach Loop failure

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis

I have created a lookup for a list of IDs and a subsequent Foreach loop to run an sql stmt for each ID.

[image]

My variable for catching the list of IDs is called MissingRecordIDs and is of type Object.  In the Foreach container I map each value to a variable called RecordID of type Int32.  No fancy scripts - I followed these instructions: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis-/ (without the file loading part - I am just running an SQL stmt).

It runs fine from within SSIS, but when I deploy it my Integration Services Catalogue in MSSQL it fails.

This is the error I get when running from SQL Mgt Studio:
[image]

I thought I could just put a Precendence Constraint after MissingRecordsIDs get filled to check for NULL and skip the Foreach loop if necessary - but I can't figure out how to check for NULL in an Object variable?

Here is the Variable declaration and Object getting enumerated:
[image]

And here is the Variable mapping:
[image]

The SQL stmt that is in 'Lookup missing Orders':

```
 select  distinct cast(od.order_id as int) as order_id
 from invman_staging.staging.invman_OrderDetails_cdc od
 LEFT OUTER JOIN invman_staging.staging.invman_Orders_cdc o
 on o.order_id = od.order_id and o.BatchID = ?
 where od.BatchID =  ?
 and o.order_id is null
 and od.order_id is not null
```

In the current environment this query returns nothing - there are no missing Orders, so I don't want to go into the 'Foreach Order Loop' at all.

Comment: You can't apply any expressions against a datatype of Object. You can use a Script Task to test it but not an Expression. Wouldn't it be cleaner to just add a filter to your Execute SQL Task to only bring back rows `WHERE RecordID IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I was thinking the MissingRecordIDs variable was empty - and therefore NULL.  You think one of the records is NULL?  I can filter for that, I will try it.

Comment: `The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::RecordID" differs from the current variable type (Int32)`

Comment: I added the suggested filter to the SQL and it didn't make a difference.   And I can see when I run the package in SSIS the foreach loop does not execute (with my current data there are no MissingRecordIDs).  Something seems to be different in the SQL Mgt Studio environment, I was thinking testing for NULL and skipping the loop would help...

Comment: I added the screenshots and query @billinkc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue Microsoft is aware of: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742282/ssis-2012-wont-assign-null-values-from-sql-queries-to-variables-of-type-string-inside-a-foreach-loop

I would suggest to add an *ISNULL(RecordID, 0)* to the query as well as set an expression to the component "Load missing Orders" in order to enable it only when RecordID != 0.

Comment: This is helpful and I didn't see this - so I marked it as the answer.  But it seems like my problem was a little more unusual.  I was having some other connection issues as well - so I deleted my SSIS project from SSMS and carefully re-checked all the Connection in SSIS - made sure they were the right authentication type and server and then redeployed.  Everything works fine now.  Not sure how - but I think the Connection String was causing unpredicatable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't NULL causing the problem, the ID value which I loaded from database was stored as nvarchar(50), even if it was a integer, I attempted to use it as integer in SSIS and it kept giving me the same error message, this worked for me:

```
SELECT CAST(id as INT) FROM dbo.Table
```